# Using a String as an identifier when creating a new Object

Tags: java, object

I have a String eg:

1,TSM,501,SM0156,John Thorne,BCO200,24,30,2,CSM,500,AC1157,Peter Jones,BCO104,24,60,...

The string represents a list of people within a department.
The "SM0156" & "AC1157" are their unique identifiers within the department

I would like to loop through the string and create a new 'person object' every time I meet an identifier. The object is then stored in an ArrayList. I believe I could do this with the following code:

```
deptList.add(new = PersonDetails());
```

This creates my object but I want to be able to reference it later possibly by the unique identifier! Whilst looping through the original string i have extracted out the identifier in this case "SM0156". I was hoping there was a way to then use this as the reference to the object EG

```
PersonDetails "SM0156" = new PersonDetails();
deptList.add("SM0156");
```

Obviously here "SM0156" represents a string but surely I could convert it somehow to use as an reference to my new PersonObject??

Thanks for any help in advance..

Comment: Use a `Map<String, PersonDetails>` to store your `PersonDetails` objects so that you can look them up by id. See [The Map Interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html) in Oracle's Java Tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

You do not want to attempt this. Store your details in a collection and depending on the collection you should use it accordingly.

If you choose an `ArrayList`, make sure your `PersonDetails` class has a field `Id` which you can look up (or create a new class that holds an `Id` and a `PersonDetails` object).

Another solution is creating a `Map<String, PersonDetails>` to map the `Id` to the person.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)`<String, PersonDetails>`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use HashMaps. HashMaps stores the objects with key/value principal.

http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-use-hashmap-tutorial-java/